# How can I convert iso-like date in dataframe such as '2022-10-28T08:00:19Z' to readable date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

I'm kinda new in Python.. help me find the solution.. I would like to convert iso-like date such as "2022-10-28T08:00:19Z" in a dataframe column into readable like '2022-10-28' or '28-10'2022' so I can filter and count the data if date >= '01-01-2022' then show the data.

this is the example of data:

```
date_published

2022-10-28T08:00:19Z
2022-10-28T05:00:08Z
2022-10-28T03:00:13Z
2022-10-27T13:55:38Z
2022-10-27T13:21:36Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['date_published']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_published']).dt.date
```